# Deploying PHP project to Openshift: failed to open stream

Tags: php, openshift

I have a PHP project with the following structure:

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJQEc.png)

I'm getting this an error that says:

```
Warning: require(../app/view/home.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/app-root/src/index.php on line 22

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '../app/view/home.php' (include_path='.:/opt/app-root/src:/opt/rh/rh-php70/root/usr/share/pear') in /opt/app-root/src/index.php on line 22
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Update: 
[Project structure on Openshift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTtZp.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please can you post the output of `pwd && ls -lR` to a paste bin service.

Answer (score 0):

I see in you image of your folder structure you have folders for public and app containing the code, but the errors from your deployment look like the code is no longer in public public but in  src.. are you sure the relative links are still correctly configured?

Has `index.php` maybe moved to the root and the link to `../abc/xyz.php` should be updated to `abc/xyz.php`?

Comment: I've updated my question. It seems that index.php is in /public_html. :\

Comment: @MarcusKyrilLim the error message above says otherwise, the file the error comes from is /opt/app-root/src/index.php - nothing about public_html.